# Magento install incomplete at user config - 65%

Tags: php, magento

I'm front-end and I'm new to PHP.

I'm trying to install Magneto and it's outputing errors and is incomplete,

It started failing at user config (65%),

And the console is outputing me these errors.

> Installing user configuration... [ERROR] exception 'Exception' with
>   message 'Warning: SessionHandler::read():
>   open(timeout=5&retry_interval=15/sess_6d6a280a2e57b283660fc6236d79caac,
>   O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in
>   /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php
>   on line 74' in
>   /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61

Please help me, Here's the full output from the console.

```
Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...

Enabling Maintenance Mode...

Installing deployment configuration...

Installing database schema:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Theme':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Customer':

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':

Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Cms':

Module 'Magento_Rule':

Module 'Magento_Catalog':

Module 'Magento_Search':

Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Widget':

Module 'Magento_Quote':

Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':

Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':

Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Config':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Msrp':

Module 'Magento_Contact':

Module 'Magento_Cookie':

Module 'Magento_Cron':

Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':

Module 'Magento_Bundle':

Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Deploy':

Module 'Magento_Developer':

Module 'Magento_Dhl':

Module 'Magento_Authorization':

Module 'Magento_Downloadable':

Module 'Magento_ImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Payment':

Module 'Magento_Email':

Module 'Magento_User':

Module 'Magento_Fedex':

Module 'Magento_Sales':

Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':

Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':

Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Checkout':

Module 'Magento_Integration':

Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Marketplace':

Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':

Module 'Magento_Multishipping':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':

Module 'Magento_Newsletter':

Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':

Module 'Magento_SalesRule':

Module 'Magento_PageCache':

Module 'Magento_Captcha':

Module 'Magento_Paypal':

Module 'Magento_Persistent':

Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':

Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':

Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':

Module 'Magento_Reports':

Module 'Magento_RequireJs':

Module 'Magento_Review':

Module 'Magento_Rss':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':

Module 'Magento_Braintree':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':

Module 'Magento_SampleData':

Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':

Module 'Magento_SendFriend':

Module 'Magento_Ui':

Module 'Magento_Sitemap':

Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':

Module 'Magento_Swagger':

Module 'Magento_Swatches':

Module 'Magento_Tax':

Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':

Module 'Magento_Translation':

Module 'Magento_Shipping':

Module 'Magento_Ups':

Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':

Module 'Magento_Usps':

Module 'Magento_Variable':

Module 'Magento_Version':

Module 'Magento_Webapi':

Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':

Module 'Magento_Weee':

Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':

Module 'Magento_Wishlist':

Schema post-updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Theme':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Customer':

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Running recurring.. 

Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Cms':

Module 'Magento_Rule':

Module 'Magento_Catalog':

Module 'Magento_Search':

Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Widget':

Module 'Magento_Quote':

Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':

Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':

Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Config':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Msrp':

Module 'Magento_Contact':

Module 'Magento_Cookie':

Module 'Magento_Cron':

Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':

Module 'Magento_Bundle':

Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Deploy':

Module 'Magento_Developer':

Module 'Magento_Dhl':

Module 'Magento_Authorization':

Module 'Magento_Downloadable':

Module 'Magento_ImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Payment':

Module 'Magento_Email':

Module 'Magento_User':

Module 'Magento_Fedex':

Module 'Magento_Sales':

Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':

Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':

Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Checkout':

Module 'Magento_Integration':

Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Marketplace':

Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':

Module 'Magento_Multishipping':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':

Module 'Magento_Newsletter':

Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':

Module 'Magento_SalesRule':

Module 'Magento_PageCache':

Module 'Magento_Captcha':

Module 'Magento_Paypal':

Module 'Magento_Persistent':

Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':

Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':

Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':

Module 'Magento_Reports':

Module 'Magento_RequireJs':

Module 'Magento_Review':

Module 'Magento_Rss':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':

Module 'Magento_Braintree':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':

Module 'Magento_SampleData':

Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':

Module 'Magento_SendFriend':

Module 'Magento_Ui':

Module 'Magento_Sitemap':

Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':

Module 'Magento_Swagger':

Module 'Magento_Swatches':

Module 'Magento_Tax':

Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':

Module 'Magento_Translation':

Module 'Magento_Shipping':

Module 'Magento_Ups':

Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':

Module 'Magento_Usps':

Module 'Magento_Variable':

Module 'Magento_Version':

Module 'Magento_Webapi':

Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':

Module 'Magento_Weee':

Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':

Module 'Magento_Wishlist':


Installing user configuration...
[ERROR] exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(timeout=5&amp;retry_interval=15/sess_6d6a280a2e57b283660fc6236d79caac, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php on line 74' in /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'SessionHandler:...', '/var/sites/s/sp...', 74, Array)
#1 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php(74): SessionHandler->read('6d6a280a2e57b28...')
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler->read('6d6a280a2e57b28...')
#3 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(189): session_start()
#4 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(130): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start()
#5 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth/Session.php(98): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Validator), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Storage), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\App\State))
#6 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(148): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Validator), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Storage), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\App\State), Object(Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy), Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Url), Object(Magento\Backend\App\Config))
#7 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Backend...', Array)
#8 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Backend...')
#9 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(236): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Backend...')
#10 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Backend...', NULL, 'session', 'Magento\\Backend...')
#11 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Backend...', Array, Array)
#12 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Backend...')
#13 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(236): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#14 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'roleLocator', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
#15 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#16 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#17 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(236): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#18 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'authorization', 'Magento\\Config\\...')
#19 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Config\\...', Array, Array)
#20 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Config\\...', Array)
#21 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(238): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Config\\...')
#22 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Config\\...', NULL, 'element', 'Magento\\Config\\...')
#23 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Config\\...', Array, Array)
#24 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Config\\...')
#25 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(236): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Config\\...')
#26 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Config\\...', NULL, 'childrenIterato...', 'Magento\\Config\\...')
#27 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Config\\...', Array, Array)
#28 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Config\\...', Array)
#29 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(238): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Config\\...')
#30 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Config\\...', NULL, 'element', 'Magento\\Config\\...')
#31 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Config\\...', Array, Array)
#32 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Config\\...')
#33 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(236): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Config\\...')
#34 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Config\\...', NULL, 'tabIterator', 'Magento\\Config\\...')
#35 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Config\\...', Array, Array)
#36 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Config\\...')
#37 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(236): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Config\\...')
#38 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Config\\...', NULL, 'configStructure', 'Magento\\Config\\...')
#39 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Config\\...', Array, Array)
#40 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Config\\...', Array)
#41 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Factory.php(35): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Config\\...', Array)
#42 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(848): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Factory->create()
#43 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installUserConfig(Array)
#44 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(331): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#45 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(97): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
#46 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
#47 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#48 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#49 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#50 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#51 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#52 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#53 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#54 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#55 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#56 /var/sites/s/specscorner.co.uk/public_html/setup/index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#57 {main}
```

Comment: **answer:** the server did not have the storage capacity necessary to run and install Magento. My host recommended to use a dedicated server package instead of their cloud hosting package.